# Trying to set the width from the page

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

```
if ((bool)Session["Conect"])
{
    logdiv.Visible = false;
    Usernamec.InnerHtml = (string)Session["CurentUserid"];
    Connected.Visible = true;
    SqlCommand exp = new SqlCommand("SELECT xp FROM[User] Where Username = @username", c);
    exp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", (string)Session["CurentUserid"]);
    c.Open();
    Session["exp"] = (int)exp.ExecuteScalar();
    c.Close();
    int b = (int)Session["exp"] / 3;
    string a = b + "%";
    xp.Style.Add("width", a);
}
```

why it is not working?
(not an eror the width does not change...)

Comment: What does `a` end up being? Please only include the relevant code, in this case it's the last line only, assuming you tell us `a`.

Comment: ok... a is the string of width it is the session devide by 300 and with %

Comment: Yes, but tell us the *actual* value for which it is failing. For all we know the sql statement is returning -1000

Comment: ok i update it it should be 3.
i trie to put at the Session 0 100 and 200 non worked all time its 0